# Page reload without refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Well, I need to refresh the page without giving a refresh, I'm currently doing so.
When the page loads I keep the contents of the html body in a variable, and when I click the button I delete the contents of the html body and add the value of the variable in it.
So I update the body without giving refresh.
The problem is that I use the datepicker plugin and when the body is rewritten by the variable datepicker does not work.
When  load the page, I save the html like this:

```
currentBody = $('body').html();
```

when I click the button, do so:

```
$('body').html('');
$('body').html(currentBody);
$('#id_ship_date').datepicker();
```

But, unsuccessfully.

this is all because I have a form and the fields it is dynamically added by the user, there need a reset button that everything he did on the page, remove everything that he added and remove all the result of queries made ​​by him.

Comment: This sound like an XY-problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem what is the problem you're trying to solve? Why are you doing a whole page 'refresh'?

Comment: Why don't you use `localStorage`?

Comment: @イオニカビザウ I think finding out the actual problem would be a better way to help, rather than stabbing in the dark.

Comment: @Archer I agree, but that can be a solution, I guess..

Comment: Just a note to help you with all of your js, you should almost certainly be using the `var` keyword like so `var currentBody = $('body').html();`. Also, use of `$` is nice for noting that something is a jQuery object... I would use this `$body` as my variable name in this case.

Comment: Sorry, my first time here. I redid my question.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to reinitialize the datepicker.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-refresh

`$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "refresh" );`

Comment: refresh likely won't work, all the body elements of DOM have been replaced, have to reinitialize plugin

Comment: True, then a `$(".selector").datepicker();` should reinitialize.

Comment: still unsuccessfully.

Comment: If you could explain what your problem actually is, maybe we can come up with a better solution than removing the entire body and replacing it.